# Set limits when plotting degree distribution of a network with igraph

Tags: r, networking, plot, igraph, degrees

I know this is probably trivial, but for some reason, I'm not able to put limits on the following graph:

```
deg_distrib <- plot(degree_distribution(g, mode='total', loop = FALSE))
```

This code works, but the values on the x-axis go up to 200, while the max value of x is 40.
Is there a way I can put a limit mechanically? I tried many things, e.g. the one below, but nothing seems to work.

```
deg_distrib <- plot(degree_distribution(g, mode='total', loop = FALSE), xlim= 50)
```

Thanks for any help, and sorry if this is too trivial.

Comment: for a basic plot, you should be able to set limits as `xlim = c(min, max)` ... can you try `xlim = c(1, 50)` for your example? also, I'm confused about difference in expected maximum values; degree_distribution should return a numeric vector the same length as maximum degree plus one.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. I had tried your solution already, but setting 0 as minimum value. it didn't work and didn't want to exclude 0 as it has a high frequency in the dataset. but apparently it does not disappear with your solution.